# (SQL) Join tables and order the final result

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, union, left-join

`table1`, `table2` and `table3` have different columns but all have an `OrderDate` column. I want to get a result set of rows from all 3 tables, and I want the final result set to be sorted by `OrderDate`.

```
( select * from table1 LEFT  join table2 on 0=1 LEFT  join table3 on 0=1
     where somedate <= table1.orderdate ) 

union all

( select * from table1 RIGHT join table2 on 0=1 LEFT  join table3 on 0=1   
     where somedate <= table2.orderdate ) 

union all

( select * from table1 RIGHT join table2 on 0=1 RIGHT join table3 on 0=1
    where somedate <= table3.orderdate )
```

This works, but I want this result set to be ordered by `orderdate`, so I add:

```
order by case when table1.orderdate is not null then table1.orderdate
              when table2.orderdate is not null then table2.orderdate
              else table3.orderdate end
```

SQL Server returns the error "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator."

If I replace

```
select *
```

by

```
select *, table1.orderdate, table2.orderdate, table3.orderdate
```

I get the same error.

Huh? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using a Common Table Expression, here is what I did:

```
WITH JoinedTable as
(
    ( select table1.col1 as t1col1, table2.col2 as t1col2 [etc...] 
      from table1 LEFT  join table2 on 0=1 LEFT  join table3 on 0=1
      where somedate <= table1.orderdate ) 

    union all

    ( select table1.col1 as t1col1, table2.col2 as t1col2 [etc...] 
      from table1 RIGHT join table2 on 0=1 LEFT  join table3 on 0=1   
      where somedate <= table2.orderdate ) 

    union all

    ( select table1.col1 as t1col1, table2.col2 as t1col2 [etc...] 
      from table1 RIGHT join table2 on 0=1 RIGHT join table3 on 0=1
      where somedate <= table3.orderdate )
)

select *, case when t1orderdate is not null then t1orderdate
               when t2orderdate is not null then t2orderdate
               else t3orderdate end
               AS DateForOrderingResultSet
from JoinedTable order by DateForOrderingResultSet
```

The

```
table1.col1 as t1col1, table2.col2 as t1col2 [etc...]
```

which replaces `*` cannot be avoided if `table1`, `table2`, `table3` have identical column names (for example `ID`) otherwise SQL Server throws an error saying `JoinedTable.ID` is ambiguous: it has no way to know if this means `table1.ID` or `table2.ID` or `table3.ID`.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
Select * from 
(( select * from table1 LEFT  join table2 on 0=1 LEFT  join table3
     where somedate <= table1.orderdate ) 

union all

( select * from table1 RIGHT join table2 on 0=1 LEFT  join table3    
     where somedate <= table2.orderdate ) 

union all

( select * from table1 RIGHT join table2 on 0=1 RIGHT join table3
    where somedate <= table3.orderdate )) A

Order by A.orderdate
```

Comment: SQL Server throws an error saying the column 'ID' was specified multiple times for 'A'. But even if this is solved with aliases, do you want to use orderdate from table1, table2 or table3? That's the problem, in any row of the result set, 2 of the 3 columns table1.orderdate, table2.orderdate, table3.orderdate is null since this is an outer join. I want to order the result set depending on the one which is not null...

Comment: You can use a where clause and specify : where A.orderDate is not null.

Comment: BTW does this query returns any result :( select * from table1 LEFT  join table2 on 0=1 LEFT  join table3
     where somedate <= table1.orderdate ) 

union all

( select * from table1 RIGHT join table2 on 0=1 LEFT  join table3    
     where somedate <= table2.orderdate ) 

union all

( select * from table1 RIGHT join table2 on 0=1 RIGHT join table3
    where somedate <= table3.orderdate ) ?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in my OP the query returns the correct result set but it's not ordered. I have solved the problem and written the solution above, thanks for the ideas and for taking an interest in my problem.